# How can I color just the outside \left and \right brackets?

Tags: math-mode, color, brackets

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\begin{document}
\[
\left(
\frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{\textcolor{red}{2a}}
\right)  
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Above I have a simple formula where I have colored a part of the formula.

How can I color just the outside `\left (` and `\right )` brackets?

Answer (score 11):

(I've updated answer in order to incorporate David Carlisle's suggestion to mention the new-ish `\mathcolor` macro.)

I can think of three solutions. The first requires having access to a fairly recent TeX distribution -- mid-2022 or even more recent. The second and third solutions should work with older TeX distributions as well.

1. With a new-ish TeX distribution (mid-2022 or more recent), there's the command `\mathcolor`:

   ```
   \mathcolor{red}{\left(}
   ...
   \mathcolor{red}{\right)}
   ```

   where `...` denotes the math expression being surrounded by the tall parentheses.
2. Encase the `\left(` and `\right)` directives in pairs of color-switching `\color` directives, i.e.,

   ```
   \color{red} \left( \color{black}
   ...
   \color{red} \right) \color{black}
   ```
3. Give up on auto-sizing the tall parentheses and run `\textcolor` on `\Biggl(` and `\Biggr(`, say.

   ```
   \textcolor{red}{\Biggl(}
   ...
   \textcolor{red}{\Biggr)}
   ```

---

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor} % for \textcolor and \mathcolor macros
\begin{document}
\[
   \mathcolor{red}{\left(}
   \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
   \mathcolor{red}{\right)}
\quad\cdots\quad
   \color{red} \left( \color{black}
   \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
   \color{red} \right) \color{black}
\quad\cdots\quad
   \textcolor{red}{\Biggl(}
   \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a}
   \textcolor{red}{\Biggr)}
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: even better to use the new(ish) \mathcolor rather than \textcolor

Comment: @DavidCarlisle - Great suggestion! I'll update my answer right away.